Annotation processor 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' not found with gradle 6
an error occur when I use gradle 6 and jpamodel gen .
here is the error.
> Configure project :module2
Args for compileJava are [-parameters, -processor, org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor]

> Task :module2:compileJpaModelgen FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':module2:compileJpaModelgen'.
> Annotation processor 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' not found


here is my config
    implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.16.Final')
    annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.16.Final')

I carring on  try select diff version of gradle 6/7 , but fail .
